# Is Q-Point in Transistor constant? For different configuration if same transistor is used?

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn, biasing

Via IV-Characteristics, for specific Ib, I got the Q-Point and using the same value of the Q-Point, I constructed a common emitter configuration biasing circuit that its V_ce = Q-Point_Voltageafter adjusting the value of the resistance. May I know the Q-Point, i_b(to find r_pi) remain constant?

Comment: While the value of an active mode \$\beta\$ for a specific BJT can have a remarkably constant value over three to five orders of magnitude of \$I_\text{C}\$, it's significantly affected by temperature. Also, it can vary substantially also between two different BJTs of the same part number. So you can't count on its value being the same between two BJTs in the same circuit or between different temperatures with the same BJT in the same circuit. You need to design circuits which apply either local or global NFB to cope and to accept some imprecision in your knowledge of the DC operating point.

Comment: An emitter follower may need lowest possible Cin (for highest Zin); you can bootstrap the base, or bias for very high Vbc voltage which leaves little voltage across the Re and produces large delta_I_emitter and large distortion. There are tradeoffs.